# Is a computer wired controlled sd card or USB flash drive feasible (like the Scylla cards connected with a laptop in prison break)?

Tags: usb, flash, usb-device, sd, data-storage

Is a computer wired controlled sd card or USB flash drive feasible (like the Scylla cards connected with a laptop in prison break)?

It means there is no storage on the flash drive itself. When a computer reads the flash drive it actually reads from another computer being wired connected with the flash drive.

Can we achieve this function by running software or adding some kind of adaptor to simulate the flash drive storage and the data in it?

Like this scenario, you wanna try a new os on raspberry pi you have to burn the IMG to the sd card. If there is some kind of adaptor you can just connect to the sd card slot and set up a software on your computer, you can just boot the raspberry pi without waiting several minutes to burn an image.

I just found a thread from superuser [is-there-software-to-fully-emulate-a-usb-hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/391679/is-there-software-to-fully-emulate-a-usb-hard-drive).

Update after bobflux answered: At first I thought it would be a hardware-related question but now it's basicly a software-related question.
[configure-linux-system-as-an-otg-device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386945/configure-linux-system-as-an-otg-device)
[use-a-linux-directory-as-a-usb-otg-device-to-an-android-phone](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132625/use-a-linux-directory-as-a-usb-otg-device-to-an-android-phone)
[make-a-computer-act-as-a-virtual-usb-device-for-other-equipments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120368/make-a-computer-act-as-a-virtual-usb-device-for-other-equipments)

[image: Scylla cards connected with a laptop]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. What's a "computer wired controlled SD card"? Also, " feasible" in which sense? And, what does this have to do with electronics engineering?

Comment: @mmmm It means there is no storage on the flash drive itself. When a computer reads the flash drive it actually reads from another computer being wired connected with the flash drive. "feasible" means can we achieve this function by running software or adding some kind of adaptor to simulate the storage the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For USB it's rather simple: any device implementing USB Mass Storage Class will be seen by the host as such. It can be implemented on anything that can run code, and it doesn't require much.

However if your storage requirements are a bit chunky, like a Raspberry Pi OS image, I'd suggest [Linux USB Gadget Mass Storage](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/usb/mass-storage.html).

Linux USB Gadget is software that turns any computer running Linux, like a PC or a RPi, into a USB device. This device can be configured to present as USB mass storage (it can also present as a fake printer, keyboard, soundcard, anything really). And since it's linux running on a computer with network access, it could serve data from local storage or even network.

However, it cannot serve individual files because USB mass storage is a block device, it has no idea what a filesystem is, it just stores blocks. In your case that wouldn't be a problem since your file is the image of a block device image anyway. I've never tried it, so don't ask how to configure it, but I've seen a guy use USB-gadget to turn a Raspberry Pi into a fully featured USB2 soundcard (using the cpu as DSP), so if that works, it shouldn't have too much trouble serving a few blocks from an image file.

Comment: Thank you. It's really an eye-opening Gadget .

Comment: Yeah every android phone these days has a mass storage device gadget mode!

Answer (score 2):

> When a computer reads the flash drive it actually reads from another computer being wired connected with the flash drive.

An SD card *is* a computer. You should read what an card actually is: a computer that responds to commands from the host. Some of these command should make it deliver data from its internal storage.

What it actually does is fully and completely up to the SD card's programming. Again, an SD card is just a computer with a few commands that it reacts to.

So, yeah, what you describe is done, it's done to develop SD cards and card readers, it's done to test software and it can be done in arbitrary ways.

Comment: Oh, yes. "An SD card is a computer". Absolutely achievable. thanks.

Comment: So is USB stick. You can make a USB stick with a microcontroller that acts as a USB device with mass storage type. Then when some USB host requests data, it's up to the microcontroller to fetch the data from say a memory chip or network or another computer. Should be slightly easier pretending to be a USB mass storage device than pretending to be an SD card.

Comment: @Jack it really is. That every SD card is a computer really just means that any sufficiently programmed computer can do the job of an SD card, given it has the physical interface, which really isn't that complex. As justme says, USB sticks are very much the same.

Answer (score 0):

No it would not be secure but possible as the Scylla box itself contains all the data which in itself is possibly hackable and the memory cards are just keys that were all required to decode the entire key.

The SC card could just be the unique ID burnt into every peripheral device which includes the Mfg coded name and model# , rev and s/n.

If the box were encrypted with Schneier’s Two Fish the runner up to the AEC2000 contest that was to find the best NSA approved replacement for banking DES and DESx3 encryption after Y2K, it would be harder to crack.